In EMR Serverless is there a way to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that pyodbc lib can be used in the python virtual env
I am trying to run my existing python script(with native python non-spark) directly in Serverless using EMR Studio.
Our goal is to execute native Python scripts directly on EMR serverless. To achieve this, we've created Python virtual environment packaged into a tar file named "pyspark_ge.tar.gz", which is stored on S3 along with the Python scripts.
Despite our efforts, we've encountered the following error.
import pyodbc 
ImportError : libodbc.so.2 : cannot open file: No such file or directory

Could you assist us in understanding how we can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in the serverless environment? or any other way to do this?
We have set the spark properties too for setting the --archives to use tar file on s3.
Also the snippet used in dockerfile to create python environment packaged in tar file is same as below:
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2023-minimal AS base
RUN dnf install -y gcc python3 python3-devel
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
#Update package lists and install unixodbc without sudo
RUN dnf install -y unixODBC-devel
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install \
    openpyxl==3.1.2 \
    packaging==23.2 \
    pandas==2.1.4 \
    msal==1.27.0 \
    psycopg2-binary==2.9.9 \
    py4j==0.10.9.7 \
    pyarrow==15.0.2 \
    pyodbc==5.1.0 \
    venv-pack==0.2.0 

RUN mkdir /output && venv-pack -o /output/pyspark_ge.tar.gz
FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/pyspark_ge.tar.gz / 

